# Display pdf file stored on local disk with in Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: forms, oracle

I switched to other architecture. Now i save all pdfs on local disk from where i run the forms. (i.e client) database is stored on server. My requirement is when user clicks on form for some particular employee, respective pdf from the local disk should open. Hope this would be easy to answer. I have not worked in Oracle forms but have to tackle this requirement so apologies for a primitive question. i used host and client_host commands but get error like "host/client_host" not defined. and web.show_document couldnt be used since i am not referring to the forms via browser and forms are not on server but on client (where the pdf documents folder is placed).

```
Last but not least. I am using Oracle Forms 6i
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .......been more than a week......  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to open the file from local disk with the help of start command as follows:-

```
Begin
   host("start 'c:\test.pdf'");
End;
```

Thanks.