# How to view BLOB file from oracle db

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

I have saved pdf files into `BLOB` column . Now I need to retrieve and view them. I am using `Oracle forms developer 6i` and `Oracle 10g`. Can anybody help me???

Comment: Please read the following link, it may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561960/display-pdf-file-stored-on-local-disk-with-in-oracle-forms-6i

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use UTIL_FILE. Considering you need to save the file to C:\, below is a sample snippet

```
declare 
  fileHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fileHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\', 'test_file.pdf', 'w');
  UTL_FILE.PUT(fileHandle, <your blob variable>);
```